# windows mobile & google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, windows-phone-7.1

im doing a project with windows mobile .net framework

and i need to track every page with google analytics

therefore i create a web browser on every page and hidden it

the web browser will include a local html page

the html page has embed google analytics

however if i use traditional method or async method to integrate GA, it will throw js error with unspecified error, but the html is working if i put it to webserver

therefore i build a GA tracking image url to log the pageview and visitor count, however i found that the cookie can not be save, those every page will generate a new visitor count

any advise

Comment: Can you try to be a bit more clear about what you're doing? As it stands, I can't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: windows mobile and Windows phone 7 aren't the same thing - which are you targeting?

Comment: oh it should be Windows phone 7.1

Comment: So, you are making an app for WP7.1, and you want to track visitors behavior in your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are simply trying to add GA tracking to your 
WP7 app. If that is the case, you do not have to use a web browser or a tracking image to accomplish this. There is a project over on GitHub that will allow you to do this right in your .xaml pages.

https://github.com/maartenba/GoogleAnalyticsTracker

Get the code, compile it and add a reference to the lib in your phone project, then in your xaml code behind:

```
Loaded += (s, e) => {
                          using (var tracker = new Tracker("UA-XXXXXXXX-X", "appname")) {
                            tracker.TrackPageView("MainPage", "Main");
                          }
                    };
```

Put your GA account info in there for the Tracker object
And presto, you have GA tracking.

HTH

Comment: million Thanks, let me try it first

Comment: Sorry, my wrong comment perviouly, the lib isnt work for me, as i cant build it, and it is using mvc framework, but the official MS lib for ga is work for me, but it is hard to use and not able to track UV, BTW million THX